# Payara glassfish integration with SAML2 Service provider

Tags: glassfish, single-sign-on, saml, payara

- Our application is currently running on payara glassfish
- There is an initiative to have SSO setup for different modules of our organization over SAML2
- Online resources point out Shibbolith SP on apache + mod_jk to glassfish

Is there any recommended approach from the community ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Online sources from payara community mention only support for openAM

http://blog.payara.fish/forgerock-integration-with-payara-server-part-1-installation